# Applying rack awareness on Pyspark Structured Streaming running on Kubernetes and reading from AWS MSK

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, aws-msk

**I have a Pyspark Structured Streaming application in the following setup:**
Pyspark - version 3.0.1, running on AWS EKS using the Spark operator.
Kafka - running on AWS MSK with a cluster running Apache Kafka version of 2.8.1 and `replica.selector.class=org.apache.kafka.common.replica.RackAwareReplicaSelector` is configured at the cluster configurations (i.e rack awareness is enabled on cluster side).

**The flow:**
The application reads from Kafka, performs batch processing in 5 minutes intervals, and writes to Kafka again. Both my MSK cluster and the ASG running the instances of my Spark executors are spread on the same AZ's.
I wish to leverage the rack awareness mechanism to allow the Spark executors to read from the closest replica.
I wish to do something like the following:

1. When spawning new executors on new pods, extract the broker.rack corresponding to the same AZ.
2. Inject that broker.rack as an environmental variable and initialize the Spark kafka consumer with a client.rack matching that broker.rack parameter.

Is this possible? Or any other solution?

Comment: You could try using boto3 or other AWS API to fetch the region/az when then executors start, then update the client configs? (Use `kafka.` prefix to set client properties)

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thank you for your response. I thought about it myself, but it won't work. The spark driver is the one who will execute this code and it will set a constant kafka.client.rack value for all executors - causing them all to read from a single broker.

Comment: You wouldn't hard-code the value, though. Each executor would need to query the AWS IMDS

Comment: Perhaps I do not understand you completely, but only the driver executes the Python script and passes the variable's values to the executors along with the logical plan - they do not each run the script themselves (only the logical plan). So even if it's not hard coded, all the executors would still get the same value as the driver.